# CSS: IFrame is not responsive, and I have a media gap

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

**Updated 03-09-2015:**

Please look at <s>http://jsfiddle.net/omarjuvera/9kkocc82/6/</s>
http://jsfiddle.net/omarjuvera/9kkocc82/11/

I have several issues:

- (MEDIA GAP) Approximately between pixel 617 and 550 (not sure of the exact measurements), the columns move into a single column; this behavior is OK. However, the width is not at 100%. There's a gap in between and it won't resize to 100%/OR at least I'd like `<div class="cell" ...` to vertically align into the center.
- ***Fixed*** IFrame is not properly resizing with the screen size.
  ***
  *I simply had to add `max-width: 100%;` to `iframe`* ***
- ***Fixed*** The 2-columns work OK. Not perfectly, but at least they work. However, the IFrame, after a certain screen size, starts to overlap with `<div class="table"...` and "overflows" outside (to the right) of the screen.
  ***
  *Same as above* ***
- ***Fixed*** I'd like to "cap" the size of table to a max of 1000px and to center the screen after that point.
   ***  *Used `@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {...`* ***

**HTML:**

```
<!-- video -->
<div class="table">
    <section class="cell">
        <h3>This is a really super long title in comparison to other videos. A really long title</h3>
        <p>Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah...</p>
        <h4>Author: John Doe</h4>
    </section>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="video">
        <iframe 
            title="Incredible Singing Cat" 
            class="youtube-player" 
            width="340" 
            height="250" 
            src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9fSde2DD8YQ"
            allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- video -->
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
        <h3>Short title</h3>
        <p>Short blah... Short blah... </p>
        <h4>Author: John Doe</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="video">
        <iframe 
            title="Another car video?!" 
            class="youtube-player" 
            width="340" 
            height="250" 
            src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9fSde2DD8YQ"
            allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- video -->
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
        <h3>Not so long title, not so short either...medim size.</h3>
        <p>Medium blah... Medium blah... Medium blah... Medium blah... Medium blah... Medium blah... Medium blah... Medium blah... Medium blah... Medium blah... Medium blah...</p>
        <h4>Author: John Doe</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="video">
        <iframe 
            title="Ophera at home" 
            class="youtube-player" 
            width="340" 
            height="250" 
            src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9fSde2DD8YQ"
            allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- video -->
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
        <h3>Some other type of title</h3>
        <p>Meh!... Meh!... Meh!... Meh!... Meh!... Meh!... Meh!... Meh!... Meh!... </p>
        <h4>Author: John Doe</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="video">
        <iframe 
            title="Living with a cat" 
            class="youtube-player" 
            width="340" 
            height="250" 
            src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9fSde2DD8YQ"
            allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- video -->
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
        <h3>What is my title?</h3>
        <p>blah... blah... blah... blah... blah... </p>
        <h4>Author: John Doe</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="video">
        <iframe 
            title="I am a dog person" 
            class="youtube-player" 
            width="340" 
            height="250" 
            src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9fSde2DD8YQ"
            allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- video -->
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
        <h3>Whateber title</h3>
        <p>blah... blah... blah... blah... blah... blah... blah... blah... blah... blah... blah...</p>
        <h4>Author: John Doe</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <iframe  class="video"
            title="Can you sing?!" 
            class="youtube-player" 
            width="340" 
            height="250" 
            src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9fSde2DD8YQ"
            allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.table {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    border: solid black 2px; /* for testing */
}
.cell {
    vertical-align: text-top;
    width: 47%;
    border: solid red 2px; /* for testing */
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0em;
    margin: 1%;
}

.video {
    text-align: center;
}

/* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */ 
@media only screen and (max-width: 610px) {
    .cell { 
        width: 99%;
        margin: 0%;
        padding: 0%;
    }

    .video {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    .table {
        margin: auto;
        width: 1000px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This answer only addresses (MEDIA GAP) because it is the only item that hasn't been fixed.

There are a number of ways of achieving this, but I like the table table-cell way.

I have created a jsfiddle. The code could use some cleaning up, but it works in more modern browsers. How far back are you looking to support?

http://jsfiddle.net/whoacowboy/9kkocc82/13/

CSS

```
html, body {
        width:100%;    
    }
    .table {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0%;
        margin:0 0 1.5em 0;
        background-color:rgba(0,255,255,.2); /* for testing */
        display:table;
    }
    .cell {
        vertical-align: top;
        width:50%;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,255,.2); /* for testing */
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 0;
        margin:0 !important;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
        box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    }
    .cell:first-child {
        padding-right:10px;

    }
    .video {
        text-align: center;
        margin:0 auto;
        background-color:black;
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%;
        padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
    }
    .video iframe,
    .video object,
    .video embed {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    iframe {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    /* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */ 
    @media only screen and (max-width: 610px) {
        .cell { 
            width: 100% !important;
            margin: 0%;
            padding: 0%;
            display:block;
        }
        .table {
            display:block;
        }
        .video {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
        .table {
            margin: auto;
            width: 1000px;
        }
    }
```

A quick search turned up a number of ways of making your youtube iframe responsive.

I used this technique.

http://avexdesigns.com/responsive-youtube-embed/

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

first point regarding the Iframe you need the width to be 100% not a fixed px number.
note width

```
<iframe title="Incredible Singing Cat" class="youtube-player" width="100% height="250px" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9fSde2DD8YQ" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

second and third they are due to css default browser implementation or what ever they call it check this link out [CSS reset](http://www.cssreset.com/), this would remove any styling that is inherited from the browser.

the fourth one you can use media query to trigger after 1000px min-width see in demo.

```
@media screen and (min-width=1000px) {
        .table {
            width:1000px;
        }
    }
```

[jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/9kkocc82/7/)

```css
/** * Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0 (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) * http://cssreset.com */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.table {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    border: solid black 2px;
    /* for testing */
}
@media screen and (min-width=1000px) {
    .table {
        width:1000px;
    }
}
.cell {
    vertical-align: text-top;
    width: 47%;
    border: solid red 2px;
    /* for testing */
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0em;
    margin: 1%;
}
.video {
    text-align: center;
}
/* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 610px) {
    .cell {
        width: 99%;
        margin: 0%;
        padding: 0%;
    }
    .video {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    .table {
        margin: auto;
        width: 1000px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- video -->
<div class="table">
    <section class="cell">
         <h3>This is a really super long title in comparison to other videos. A really long title</h3>

        <p>Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah... Blah...</p>
         <h4>Author: John Doe</h4>

    </section>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="video">
            <iframe title="Incredible Singing Cat" class="youtube-player" width="100%" height="250px" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9fSde2DD8YQ" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- video -->
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
         <h3>Short title</h3>

        <p>Short blah... Short blah...</p>
         <h4>Author: John Doe</h4>

    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="video">
            <iframe title="Another car video?!" class="youtube-player" width="100%" height="250" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9fSde2DD8YQ" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- video -->
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
         <h3>Not so long title, not so short either...medim size.</h3>

        <p>Medium blah... Medium blah... Medium blah... Medium blah... Medium blah... Medium blah... Medium blah... Medium blah... Medium blah... Medium blah... Medium blah...</p>
         <h4>Author: John Doe</h4>

    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="video">
            <iframe title="Ophera at home" class="youtube-player" width="100%" height="250" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9fSde2DD8YQ" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- video -->
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
         <h3>Some other type of title</h3>

        <p>Meh!... Meh!... Meh!... Meh!... Meh!... Meh!... Meh!... Meh!... Meh!...</p>
         <h4>Author: John Doe</h4>

    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="video">
            <iframe title="Living with a cat" class="youtube-player" width="100%" height="250" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9fSde2DD8YQ" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- video -->
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
         <h3>What is my title?</h3>

        <p>blah... blah... blah... blah... blah...</p>
         <h4>Author: John Doe</h4>

    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="video">
            <iframe title="I am a dog person" class="youtube-player" width="100%" height="250" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9fSde2DD8YQ" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- video -->
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
         <h3>Whateber title</h3>

        <p>blah... blah... blah... blah... blah... blah... blah... blah... blah... blah... blah...</p>
         <h4>Author: John Doe</h4>

    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <iframe class="video" title="Can you sing?!" class="youtube-player" width="100%" height="250" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9fSde2DD8YQ" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: another thing I noticed, if you pay attention to all videos, each video has a different size and alignment

Comment: Width is a % and media query for .table

Comment: the videos that you provided was all the same size so I assumed that they are all the same width, I had one by mistake 90% and I fixed that, if that is not what you mean please elaborate

Comment: the aspect-ratio of the video is very weird and won't properly resize.

Comment: check this out ,https://jsfiddle.net/9kkocc82/8/, if you have the video in css, and removed height from html

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.frame{
width:960px; // set as per responsive stylesheet
}
</style>
<div class="frame">
<iframe title="frame_title" class="player" width="100% height="coatent_height" src="//www.yoursite.com/" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a way and seems to work. Just set the width of .video to 100%, and don't specify height. Then change the width of iframe to 'inherit' and height to 'auto'. No idea if this is valid or cross-browser compatible. But, seems pretty fine to me.

```
.video {
    width: 100%;
}

iframe {
    width: inherit;
    height: auto;
}
```

Correct me if my method is wrong, or error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

About the last point NOT fixed:

> (MEDIA GAP) Approximately between pixel 617 and 550 (not sure of the
>   exact measurements), the columns move into a single column; this
>   behavior is OK. However, the width is not at 100%. There's a gap in
>   between and it won't resize to 100%/OR at least I'd like

Well, at that point the columns didn't really move into a single column, there are not yet any queries on play. it just happened that your elements inline-block didn't have enough room to still be on same row so they just stacked (as it is suppose to happens). I find myself very dangerous to use sizes on "%" and use inline-blocks elements insteed of floating as there's always a gap between inline-block elements difficult to handle sometimes.

Also I recomend you to always use `box-sizing: border-box;`

In your fiddle I've just added boder box to your "cell" so those provisional borders won't take space OUT of the cell (that was another reason why the inline-block elements jumped before it was time).

Then if your cells have 1% margin... your cell width might have been 48% `(1%+48+1%+1%+48+1%=100%)` but as the inline blocked elements as I mentioned above takes extra space between them I set the width of your cells to "47.5%" which is enough to prevent an early jump.

check it out here and excuse my poor english: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9kkocc82/14/)**

Answer (score 0):

I've found the best/easiest way to vertically align stuff in CSS is using flexbox. 
[CSS-Tricks complete guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Here is my modification of your CSS that is vertically aligned. I also used border-box, margin:0 and padding:0 and width:50% to get rid of the gaps.

```css
.table {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  border: solid black 2px;
  /* for testing */
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.cell {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  border: solid red 2px;
  /* for testing */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}
.video {
  text-align: center;
}
iframe {
  max-width: 100%;
}
/* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */

@media only screen and (max-width: 610px) {
  .cell {
    width: 99%;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
  }
  .video {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .table {
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
  }
}
```